# Rotate all layers in a group

Tags: photoshop-scripting

How would I go about referencing a group of layers in a script if I wanted to perform a rotation on all of them as a group, not individually? Essentially I want to rotate all my layers in the group around the center of the canvas.

Comment: If you want to rotate a group... You target the group and rotate. What part of that is giving you trouble? Also would an Action suffice?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax of performing the target and rotation. I have just started out learning javascript and can only perform layer operations. An action will not work because I am performing transformations on my group while randomly changing the values of the parameters of the transformations i.e, scale, rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something called **Transform Each Beta** => [LINK](http://blog.darkwark.com/transformEach/)

There you can download script version for **CC 2014** and **CC 2015** => [LINK](http://blog.darkwark.com/transformEach21/)

It's the same idea like in the Illustrator's "Transform Each" - you can rotate a group of images, scale them, move, or shear.

All you have to do is to install that script into `Photoshop/Presets/Scripts` folder.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'll have to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

I had surprisingly hard time understanding what you want exactly, so I hope this is close enough...

Some resources for scripting:

- [Photoshop javascript reference](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)
- [Scripting listener plugin and how to install it](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin)

  - Scripting listener is used almost the same way as Actions. You do something in photoshop and scripting listener outputs that action as javascript. In recent years, since CC, I believe, it also outputs some extra code that doesn't belong and should be ignored.
  - There's also also a script in [Xtools](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html) for converting an action file into Javascript, which more or less does the same thing. The script is called: `ActionToJavascript.jsx`.
  - Also I should mention that you can trigger Actions using javascript and you can also trigger a script from an Action. These can save a lot of time. Sometimes you can almost make something with Actions, but you need to for example save the file with a custom name, so you could create an Action that at the end triggers a script that has scripting listener generated code, where you programmatically generate the name.
- [Photoshop reference guide by Jongware](http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/)

---

I added some comment explanations in the code...

```
var targetName = 'My Example Group';
var angle = 20;

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var targetGroup = doc.layers.getByName( targetName );

// Sets our target layer as the active layer.
doc.activeLayer = targetGroup;

var docHorHalf = doc.width / 2;
var docVerHalf = doc.height / 2;

// This is a neater way to rotate a layer, but it doesn't support a custom value for the anchorpoint - http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_Layer.html#rotate
// targetGroup.rotate( 20, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER );

// This Action Manager code generated by the Scripting Listener plugin lets you define exactly where the anchor point should be:
// =======================================================
var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );
    var desc24 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref6 = new ActionReference();
        var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
        var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
        var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
        ref6.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc24.putReference( idnull, ref6 );
    var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
    var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
    var idQcsi = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsi" );
    desc24.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsi );
    var idPstn = charIDToTypeID( "Pstn" );
        var desc25 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc25.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, (doc.width / 2) ); // I changed a static value here to: (doc.width / 2)
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc25.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, (doc.height / 2) ); // I changed a static value here to: (doc.height / 2)
    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
    desc24.putObject( idPstn, idPnt, desc25 );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
        var desc26 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc26.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000 );
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc26.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, -0.000000 );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
    desc24.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc26 );
    var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
    var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
    desc24.putUnitDouble( idAngl, idAng, angle ); // I changed a static value here to: 'angle', a variable defined at the top of the script.
    var idIntr = charIDToTypeID( "Intr" );
    var idIntp = charIDToTypeID( "Intp" );
    var idBcbc = charIDToTypeID( "Bcbc" );
    desc24.putEnumerated( idIntr, idIntp, idBcbc );
executeAction( idTrnf, desc24, DialogModes.NO );
```

This is how the script works as it is:

<sup><sub>(The script is triggered 7 times in a row and then the gif loops)</sub></sup>

[image]

Comment: How do I go about uploading images on here to show an example?

Comment: @roldy should be an image icon above message box. Though I think you need to have certain amount of reports to use it. Maybe just use imgur or like Dropbox and link to it.

Comment: Oh I see. In the original message. I was trying to figure out how to do it in a comment. I'll have to edit my message later today.